# Upgrading from scipy to imageio

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, python-3.6, python-imageio

I'm quite new to Python so bear with me, I downloaded a github project for Document Forgery Detection that works with 3.6 and buried within it is `scipy.misc.imsave` which is deprecated.

The call to `scipy.misc.imsave` only has one parameter but I can't find documentation for that call, only for two parameter methods.

So when I tried to upgrade to what I found recommended online, `imageio` I replaced the calls as so.

Before

```
scipy.misc.imsave(self.imageOutputDirectory + "MarkedImage")
```

After

```
imageio.imwrite(self.imageOutputDirectory + "MarkedImage")
```

Of course this doesn't work as it expects two params. The problem is I can't figure out what the original implementation was somehow passing to scipy to reference it, is it some inherited method in the class?

Comment: *"The call to `scipy.misc.imsave` only has one parameter..."* That can't be correct.  `imsave` required at least two arguments: the filename and the array to be written to the file.

Comment: Take a look at the use of `scipy.misc.imsave` in this version of the file: https://github.com/trinity652/Document-Forgery-Detection/blob/e3ca0732eacc4348bf132d0259226e1ebf5a3901/app/ImageObject.py (scroll down to the last five lines in the file).